# How to debug shared object loading on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

How can I get better error messages when developing shared libraries with ubuntu?

I'm developing a few shared objects to be loaded by our framework due to my inability to make everything 100% proof, sometimes external dependencies are added, which cannot be found when the library is loaded at runtime.

The error message for such things is something like: Cannot open shared object file: File or directory not found. What it REALLY is saying that something failed while loading the file.

Is there any way to make gdb spit out what actually was missing?

I used ldd to see if anything big was missing, but it said that everything is found.

Comment: You could link the required shared libraries into your shared library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617286/easy-check-for-unresolved-symbols-in-shared-libraries

Should have spent more time looking....