# How to fail CMake+Clang build in case of unresolved symbols?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clang, shared-libraries

I am trying to check that my shared libraries and executables have no unresolved symbols before running them. As far as I know it is done by adding compiler option `-Wl,-z,defs`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671205/7325599).

My Linux program is built using CMake, so I add this flag in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror -pthread -Wl,-z,defs")
```

The first two options were already present to support multi-threading and treat all warnings as errors.

This works perfectly well with GCC compiler, but with Clang compiler CMake build fails in the very beginning with the error (which was missing without `-Wl,-z,defs`):

```
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:220 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfig.cmake:4 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:204 (find_package)
```

As far as I can see Clang issues the warning `-Wl,-z,defs: 'linker' input unused`, which becomes an error due to `-Werror`, and this makes CMake believe that simple program with just `#include "pthread.h"` fails, online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Wx9qKohbo

How can I force build to fail in case of unresolved symbols without suppressing "input unused" warning in Clang?

Comment: "`'linker' input unused`" - Because you have specified the **linker** flags in the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for **compiler** ones. Instead modify variables `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` (for shared libraries) and `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` (for executables). See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532853/how-can-i-add-linker-flag-for-libraries-with-cmake) for more options for linker flags.

Comment: `add_link_options("LINKER:-no-undefined")`?